# Rails: How to make a custom route from resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an Enki blog set up and the sign in's at `www.localhost:3000/admin`.`

I'm guessing that this admin url is determined by this code from routes, but, for extra security reasons, I'd like to make the login, for example,

www.localhost:3000/ilovejesus

```
Enki::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'admin' do
    resource :session
```

Based on what rake routes is telling me,  I'm guessing it's the admin_root that goes to `:controller => Admin/Dashboard, :action => 'show`' that needs to get changed.

So can anyone tell me how I might change this too, for example, localhost:3000/iloveronpaul

Rake Routes:

```
admin_session POST   /admin/session(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
   new_admin_session GET    /admin/session/new(.:format)                    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
  edit_admin_session GET    /admin/session/edit(.:format)                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
                     GET    /admin/session(.:format)                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
                     PUT    /admin/session(.:format)                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
                     DELETE /admin/session(.:format)                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/sessions"}
 preview_admin_posts POST   /admin/posts/preview(.:format)                  {:action=>"preview", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
         admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
                     POST   /admin/posts(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
      new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)                      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
     edit_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
          admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
                     PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
                     DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/posts"}
 preview_admin_pages POST   /admin/pages/preview(.:format)                  {:action=>"preview", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
         admin_pages GET    /admin/pages(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
                     POST   /admin/pages(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
      new_admin_page GET    /admin/pages/new(.:format)                      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
     edit_admin_page GET    /admin/pages/:id/edit(.:format)                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
          admin_page GET    /admin/pages/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
                     PUT    /admin/pages/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
                     DELETE /admin/pages/:id(.:format)                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/pages"}
      admin_comments GET    /admin/comments(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
                     POST   /admin/comments(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
   new_admin_comment GET    /admin/comments/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
  edit_admin_comment GET    /admin/comments/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
       admin_comment GET    /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
                     PUT    /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
                     DELETE /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/comments"}
undo_admin_undo_item POST   /admin/undo_items/:id/undo(.:format)            {:action=>"undo", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
    admin_undo_items GET    /admin/undo_items(.:format)                     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
                     POST   /admin/undo_items(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
 new_admin_undo_item GET    /admin/undo_items/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
edit_admin_undo_item GET    /admin/undo_items/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
     admin_undo_item GET    /admin/undo_items/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
                     PUT    /admin/undo_items/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
                     DELETE /admin/undo_items/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/undo_items"}
        admin_health        /admin/health(/:action)(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/health"}
          admin_root        /admin(.:format)                                {:controller=>"admin/dashboard", :action=>"show"}
            archives GET    /archives(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"archives"}
                page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)                            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages"}
                     GET    /:year/:month/:day/:slug/comments(.:format)     {:year=>/\d{4}/, :month=>/\d{2}/, :day=>/\d{2}/, :controller=>"comments", :action=>"index"}
                     POST   /:year/:month/:day/:slug/comments(.:format)     {:year=>/\d{4}/, :month=>/\d{2}/, :day=>/\d{2}/, :controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"}
                     GET    /:year/:month/:day/:slug/comments/new(.:format) {:year=>/\d{4}/, :month=>/\d{2}/, :day=>/\d{2}/, :controller=>"comments", :action=>"new"}
                     GET    /:year/:month/:day/:slug(.:format)              {:year=>/\d{4}/, :month=>/\d{2}/, :day=>/\d{2}/, :controller=>"posts", :action=>"show"}
     formatted_posts GET    /posts.:format                                  {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
               posts GET    /(:tag)(.:format)                               {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
                root        /(.:format)                                     {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a :path option to your `namespace`

```
Enki::Application.routes.draw do
  scope :module => 'admin' do
    resource :session, :path_names => { :new => "liverandonions", 
                                        :show => "ilovejesus,
                                        :edit => "iloveronpaul" }
```

I'm not sure but the `path_names` options might have to be wrapped in array.

ie.

```
    resource :session, :path_names => { [:new => "liverandonions", 
                                        :show => "ilovejesus,
                                        :edit => "iloveronpaul"] }
```

let me know which one works.

Comment: Thanks, but is that path just going to affect localhost:3000/admin or will it affect every 'admin' path in the namespace?

Comment: Every path in the name space. Here's a link to the [namespace routing documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-namespace)

Comment: O.K, but I think there's also a way just to change that one url but I can't figure it out. do you know by chance?

Comment: this is wrong. arrays in ruby can't have keys, they're just values.